# Configuration Mime Types error

Tags: 8

I have a Drupal 8 installation and am developing the site. It's not operational yet.

I have 2 problems i think are related.
First of all a selected image in a custom content type isn't uploaded or shown in new content of the content type. It is a standard image field.

When searching for a solution i got an error log saying that there is a problem with a missing MIME Map extension in sophron. When looking at the Mime types in the Configuration section, my second problem arises.

I get the following error when clicking MIME Types:

> The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
> Error: Class 'FileEye\MimeMap\MapHandler' not found in Drupal\sophron\EventSubscriber\SophronEventSubscriber->initializeMap() (line 68 of modules\sophron\src\EventSubscriber\SophronEventSubscriber.php).
> Drupal\sophron\EventSubscriber\SophronEventSubscriber->initializeMap(Object, 'sophron.map.initialize', Object)
> call_user_func(Array, Object, 'sophron.map.initialize', Object) (Line: 111)
> Drupal\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->dispatch('sophron.map.initialize', Object) (Line: 129)
> Drupal\sophron\MimeMapManager->setMapClass('Drupal\sophron\Map\DrupalMap') (Line: 105)
> Drupal\sophron\MimeMapManager->getMapClass() (Line: 152)
> Drupal\sophron\Form\SettingsForm->buildForm(Array, Object)
> call_user_func_array(Array, Array) (Line: 520)
> Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder->retrieveForm('sophron_settings', Object) (Line: 277)
> Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder->buildForm(Object, Object) (Line: 91)
> Drupal\Core\Controller\FormController->getContentResult(Object, Object)
> call_user_func_array(Array, Array) (Line: 123)
> Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber{closure}() (Line: 573)
> Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext(Object, Object) (Line: 124)
> Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->wrapControllerExecutionInRenderContext(Array, Array) (Line: 97)
> Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber{closure}() (Line: 151)
> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object, 1) (Line: 68)
> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 57)
> Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
> Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 106)
> Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->pass(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 85)
> Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
> Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 52)
> Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 23)
> Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 694)
> Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object) (Line: 19)

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: How can this be reproduced by others?

Comment: Sounds like you probably didn't use Composer to install the sophron module

Answer (score -1):

Based on the https://www.drupal.org/project/sophron module page. you should install it with

```
composer require drupal/sophron
```

the error is complaining about missed class that you need to install the module by composer way ( as what recommended in module page)

> **Installation**

> Require the module via
>
> $ composer require drupal/sophron
>
> This will download both the module and any dependency. Then, enable
> the module as usual.